# Do I need to reply back to CEO Seasonal greetings email for everyone in company?

Tags: communication, email

I am a bit confused with this situation.  I have received the company's seasonal X' mas greeting from the CEO in my company email, which she sent to everyone.

Is it appropriate to reply back in person for her greeting email?

Answer (score 10):

It depends on the size of the company -- if it's small enough that you meet the CEO regularly, then yes, you can reply or send your own greetings email (a reply kind of looks as if the CEO had to remind you). In large companies, that would just lead to the CEO receiving a lot of emails, so it wouldn't be expected there.

Comment: To put a finer point on it, if it’s a 10 person company absolutely, 100 person maybe if you are on speaking terms with them, 1000+ absolutely not unless your title starts with a capital C.

Comment: @mxyzplk-JusticeforMonica "1000+ absolutely not unless your title starts with a capital C." Or you're their secretary or something, so you know them personally.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it appropriate to reply back in person for her greeting email?

If you happen to come across this person in the hallway, break room, or what have you, then *definitely feel free to extend a thank you* back to this person.

If you feel so inclined, you could even stop by their office and say thanks in person.  Personally, I would only do this if I had spoken to them in the past in some capacity. ( *having a relationship of some kind* )

I would definitely **skip the email reply**, as they most likely will get a ton of them and it won't be read.  Whatever you do, do not **REPLY ALL** as pointed out in another answer.

Answer (score 2):

> *Is it appropriate to reply back in person for her greeting email?*

**Yes, it is appropriate to respond**, but most likely, it'll get ignored anyway.

Unless you happen to know the CEO personally or you communicate with the CEO on a regular basis, in any mid-to-large sized organization:

- The email you received and alike are sent via automated scripts, and it's sent to all. Sometimes, the emails are sent by the team managing the CEO's office (Personal secretary/ PR team).
- The same way, many times, the emails that actually reache the CEO, are pre-filtered and only the ones which need their time and attention are passed on to them.

Feel free to email a reply, but most likely it'll not reach the CEO.

So, to answer the other question

> *Do I need to reply back to CEO Seasonal greetings email for everyone in company?*

**No, you don't need to**.

As suggested by the other answers, you can wish them in-person if you bump into them, or if you feel too obliged, you can pay a visit to their cabin and greet them back.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it appropriate to reply back in person for her greeting email?

Yes, it's perfectly appropriate.

Just make sure that if she CCed everyone in the company you don't do a Reply All. It wouldn't be good to start an avalanche of email replies.